# Pillow Image.save() [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, save, file-permissions, python-imaging-library

So I am trying to loop a bunch of images in a folder, do some changes and save them in a subdirectory and I am having permission denied issues.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = 'D:/my_path/'


dirs = os.listdir( path )

new_folder = 'out'

if not os.path.exists(path + new_folder):
    os.makedirs(path + new_folder)

def resize():
    num=0
    for item in dirs:

        #print(path + item)
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item).convert('RGB')

            imResize = im.resize((64, 64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.Resize = os.rename(os.path.join(path, item),os.path.join(path, 'bad_' + str(num)) )
            imResize.save(path + new_folder, 'JPEG', quality=90)

            num+=1
        #if num > 1000:
            #break
resize()
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/my_path/out/'

Error triggers on this line `imResize.save(path + new_folder, 'JPEG', quality=90)` Any idea why?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Sometimes it will throw you this error if the path is read incorrectly. Try `path = r'D:/my_path/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
rename = 'bad_img_'

def resize():
    num=0
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item).convert('RGB')
            imResize = im.resize((64, 64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(os.path.join(save_dir, rename + str(num)) + '.JPG', 'JPEG', quality=90)
            num+=1

resize()
```

Answer (score 4):

`imResize.save(path + new_folder, 'JPEG', quality=90)` Doesn't look right to me. You have a directory named `D:/my_path/out`, and here you're trying to save the file to the name `D:/my_path/out`. That's already a directory, so you can't save a file with that same name.

Try choosing a name for your file that doesn't conflict with the name of an existing directory.

```
outputfilename = os.path.join(path, new_folder, "myoutputfile_{}.jpg".format(num))
imResize.save(outputfilename, 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Comment: Yea I just fixed it right after I posted this question. I wrote this piece of code a long time ago took me a while to figure out what was going on. See my answer below on working code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, the path is correct, but the problem appears because of the file permission. In Mac, right click file and choose `get info` and then change the permission to `read&write`.